# How do I check if my array is descending, ascending, or not sorted?

Tags: arrays, sorting

So my code works fine if the array is ascending or descending, its just that when it isn't sorted that I run into an issue. Instead of displaying "not sorted", it will display both ascending and descending. What should I do?

```
int[] array;
array= new int[]{1,5,6,11,55};
boolean answerDes= false;
boolean answerAsc= false;

for (int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++){
  if(array[i]>array[i+1])
    answerDes=true;
  if(array[i]<array[i+1])
    answerAsc=true;
}
if(answerDes)
  System.out.println("Descending");
if(answerAsc)
  System.out.println("Ascending");
if(!answerAsc && !answerDes)
  System.out.println("Not sorted");
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Since both are true when the array is unsorted both the `if`-statements pass, to avoid this you could replace the comditional statements with the one shown below, here when both are true it would go to the `else` statement

```
if(!answerDes)
    System.out.println("Ascending");
else if(!answerAsc)
   System.out.println("Descending");
else {
   System.out.println("Not sorted");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop, you are comparing just two values, consider this:

In an array that is not sorted, at one point `array[i]` may be greater than `array[i+1]`, AND then later `array[i]` may be less than `array[i+1]` meaning that both `answerDes` and `answerAsc` will get set to `true`, meaning that it will print Descending and Ascending in the if statements that contain them.

example: an array that is: [1,3,5,2,6,7] may make your `answerDes` and `answerAsc` values both true

Maybe consider different array comparison logic and then compare for 'not sorted' first and then include the ascending and descending comparison in `else` statements afterwards instead of using all `if` statements

see [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sorted-array) link for sorting arrays in C#.

P.S Try not to invent the wheel :)